# Disable items getting locked

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've been asked to turn off the posibility for users to "lock" an item.

They can do this in the Content Editor (Review > Edit). But it seems it can also happen, when users are using the "Page Editor".

Is there anyway to turn this off?

As far as I can see it's turned off in the web.config:

```
<setting name="AutomaticLockOnSave" value="false"/>
<setting name="AutomaticUnlockOnSaved" value="true"/>
<setting name="KeepLockAfterSaveForAdminUsers" value="false"/>
<setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="false"/>
<setting name="UnlockAfterCopy" value="true"/>
```

But if a user has locked an item in Sitecore, a user using the Page Editor can't edit the item, as it is locked. It says:

```
You cannot edit the current item because it is locked by: <username>
```

Is there a way to disable this feature completely?

Best regards,

Christian Willumsen

Comment: I've also asked Sitecore and they just said I could disable the buttons... not much help there

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer to this, but since you're turning up empty so far, I'll give you my initial reaction... don't try to turn it off, just make it easier for users to unlock with workflow.

If you apply a simple one-step workflow to your content, Sitecore will still automatically lock the content when they are working in it, but through a single-click workflow step your user can unlock the content item and even publish it.

Locking is there for a reason. It's annoying to users, but workflow can make it way less annoying.

Comment: Hm... well not sure if that would wokr in the case... it's a site, where people can make their own personal homepage (ie. professors at a university). And they only edit their pages on the frontend.

And my experience with workflows isn't great (both in terms of not having used them that much and when finally having used the, having them not work properly), so I'd rather just avoid them. What if I turn off workflows too ?